# How to get text into Unity?

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a basic Java program with output of "hello world". What I want to do is to write a Java script to run that program and import that into Unity so I can use it in my program in Unity.

Is there a way?

Comment: 1. **Realize that Java and Javascript are very, very different languages.** I'm assuming you mean Java. 2. Unity means a lot of different things: It's the desktop environment for Ubuntu, a Linux distribution, a game engine, and also a .NET package, among other things. 3. You are very unclear what you want to achieve. "Import that into unity so i can use it in my program in unity" doesn't tell us anything. Please clarify your question so we can better help you.

Comment: ahh Sory, didnt realize that... its unity the 3D designing program.
And i want to import text saying "forward" So that i know that my cube or character must go forward. That text should come from outside unity, like a textbox or something? i would love to read up on how to do it, but i dont know what to google to find help on this..

Comment: Because i want another/external program to give commands to my cube, to move or whatever. So i need a way to get that commands/ text into unity

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate with Unity from a Java application trough OSC(Open Sound Control) and send text, commands triggers or load an external file(xml or similar) into Unity.

Unity and Open Sound Control
http://www.sundh.com/blog/2012/07/unity-processing-demo/

Comment: Ahh Thank you! Definitely gona Read up about OSC. Will let you know what i find!

Answer (score 0):

On unity you have to use function OnGui() to show text.
In the related documentation you have many example.

For show message in a console just use in a javascript:

```
Debug.Log("Hello world");
```

Comment: ahh cool, not wat i wanted, but might be able to use this, thank you. Do you know where i can find the documents on Unity? You know where all the commands and classes etc are

Comment: You can find this by googling "Unity Scripting Reference". First link is gooood

Comment: if u have unity,just navigate the menu tab and select "Help", then u have a reference manual,scripting manual and unity manual, or visit this link: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/

Answer (score 0):

You can also put files in your /Resources folder in your unity project, then load them at run time. These can be pretty much anything. models, prefabs, materials... could be text files (maybe comma delimited txt files, that you parse) or more typically .xml files that you can easily access and extract data (text) from.

to load any resource file, use resources.load()
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use OnGui as this is bad for performance rather use Canvas to edit and place the text you prefer on or in (parent) object you want.

to make this look better put the font size higher and the width and height lower.
this will make it look sharper.

[image: Located here]